# Python Scraping Same Tags Issue

Tags: html, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itq5o.png)

I am trying to scrape the 13,767 and ignore the 2,500. Sometimes the 2,500 would be blank but my issue is my scraping code has the same tags and pulls them all when i just want the 13,767

bs.find_all('span', class_='bp-Homecard__LockedStat--value')

I used this code bs.find_all('span', class_='bp-Homecard__LockedStat--value')

Answer (score -1):

```
spans = bs.find_all('span', class_='bp-Homecard__LockedStat--value')
for span in spans:
    if span.text.strip():  # Check if the text content is not empty
        text = span.text.strip()
        break
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).